# Matter and dark energy

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, universe, dark-energy

So dark energy is the biggest thing in the universe, it keeps accelerating the expansion. But it's a constant so at some point there was a matter - dark energy equivalence. My question is how can you calculate this time and its redshift, and then work out how far the light has traveled from the dark energy - matter equivalence to now, since the universe is dark energy dominated now ?

Comment: It's exactly the same calculation as I did when calculating the transition from radiation to matter domination. Just set $\Omega_{M,0}\,a = \Omega_{\Lambda,0}\,a^4$. Do you want me to go thorough it again or can you take it from here?

Comment: I thought dark energy was constant though?

Comment: I wouldn't mind if you wanted to give me bullet points (no maths). I've been trying to get it wrapped around my head all morning, thanks

Comment: To start with, have you calculated the value of $a$ when the matter and dak energy contributions are equal? If so, what value do you get?